# Folland's real analysis, theorem 2.49

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm having difficulty in following Folland's theorem 2.49, where he states

[image]

As underlined in red, I don't understand why equation 2.50 is just a restatement of $m_*=\rho\times \sigma$ when $f$ is a characteristic function of a set. My attempt is:

> Denote $E=\Phi(F)$, then
> $$\text{LHS } = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\chi_F(x)dx = m(F) = m_*(E)$$
> $$\text{RHS } = \int_0^{\infty}\int_{S^{n-1}}\chi_F(rx')r^{n-1}d\sigma(x')dr = \int_0^{\infty}\int_{S^{n-1}}\chi_F(\Phi^{-1}(r,x'))r^{n-1}d\sigma(x')dr = ?$$

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just observe that
$$
\chi_F\circ \Phi^{-1}=\chi_E
$$
And then
$$
RHS=\int_0^{\infty}\sigma(\Phi_2(F\cap S^{n-1}_r))r^{n-1}dr=\rho\times\sigma(E).
$$
Observe that the argument of $\sigma$ is a subset of $S^{n-1}$. $\Phi_2$ stands for the second (angular) component of $\Phi$.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask about the meaning of $\Phi_2$ and $S_r^{n-1}$?

Comment: $\Phi_2(rx’)=x’$ and $S_r^{n-1}$ is the sphere of radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.